# Oracle TimeStamp Issue for Oracle from DB2

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle11g, db2, sql-timestamp

I am working in migration project where we are migrating from DB2 to Oracle. Can any one help me out on specific timestamp for this issue...

I want this format which we have in DB2

```
"timestamp": "2014-11-05T14:00:21.749Z"
```

but after using TO_CHAR in Oracle I am getting something like this

```
"timestamp": "2018-06-07T21:46:06.000Z"
```

I am using TO_CHAR(insertDTM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')

In table I have data something like this...

```
2018-05-31 09:12:46.650000000

2018-05-31 17:07:35.522939000
```

Thanks...

Comment: I don't understand your question, however using `TO_CHAR(...)` seems to be wrong in any case if you like to insert timestamp values. With `TO_CHAR()` you create a **string** as the function name implies - not a timestamp.

Comment: Actually DATE or TIMESTAMP types are not associated with any display format, they are stored in tables in internal binary format. The default display format is determined by session parameters (see [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams122.htm#REFRN10119), or you can explicitely use TO_CHAR conversion function if you want to explicitely define fixed format of converson from DATE to STRING. I don';t understand your question.

Comment: are you migrating data or are you trying to translate your db2 apps to speak 'Oracle' ?

Comment: @krokodilko, yes I want to covert timestamp to string. but as you can see after using TO_CHAR with format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' MS portion is getting tripped off. In String it is showing as "000Z" which in DB2 version "749Z". May be I just need the proper format which I can use with TO_CHAR .

Comment: Please show your code, or a [minimal, complete and verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code which everyone can run and reproduce your issue. As for now the question is unclear and I am voting to close it.